# How can I change app's language in iOS9 WITHOUT restart app?

Tags: ios9

When I change the app's language independently on the device language it doesn't work only if I restart it. I have tried several times according to answers in Stack Overflow, like:

```
#import "NSBundle+Language.h"

#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const char _bundle=0;

@interface BundleEx : NSBundle
@end

@implementation BundleEx
-(NSString*)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSBundle* bundle=objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_bundle);
    return bundle ? [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName] : [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
}
@end

@implementation NSBundle (Language)

+(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
                  {
                      object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[BundleEx class]);
                  });
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

}

@end
```

but not take effect.

I have post a notification when language changed in app's settings screen , views who listened the notification will reload views, but not worked, language just not changed.

Comment: iOS is not supporting restart app feature. You can always update it whenever a language change has been made. All the other UI (where you need to change your language) should be update inside `viewWillAppear:` method of a particular view. And yes, **this question is not iOS9 specific.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works in my demo, just set another language,and do something like  reload the view which is visible.